# Implementing Multi-Touch Controls for Camera Rotation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I’m working on a Unity project where I have a virtual joystick for player movement and a camera that I want to control separately. I’m trying to implement a specific multi-touch control scheme and need some help.

Here’s what I want to achieve:

If the player touches and holds the joystick with dragging or not, and then touches the right side of the screen, the camera should rotate.
If the player touches the right side of the screen first (without any interaction with the joystick), the camera should also rotate.
Here’s the code I have so far:

C#

```
public class JoystickControll : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler,IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler 
{

    public bool joystickBeingDragged = false;
    // ... rest of your code ...

    public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData stick)
    {
        joystickBeingDragged = true;
        // ... rest of your code ...
    }

    public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData stick)
    {
        joystickBeingDragged = false;
        // ... rest of your code ...
    }
}

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public JoystickControll joystickControll;
    private bool initialTouchOnRightHalf = false;

    private void CameraRotation()
    {
        // ... rest of your code ...

        if (initialTouchOnRightHalf || joystickControll.joystickBeingDragged)
        {
            mouseX = touch.deltaPosition.x * mouseSensetivity * Time.deltaTime;
            mouseY = touch.deltaPosition.y * mouseSensetivity * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        // ... rest of your code ...
    }
}
```

In the `CameraRotation` function, the `if (initialTouchOnRightHalf || joystickControll.joystickBeingDragged)` condition is supposed to check if either the right side of the screen was touched first or if the joystick is being touched. If either condition is true, it calculates the new mouseX and mouseY values, which are then used to rotate the camera.

However, this isn’t working as expected. The camera rotates when the joystick is dragged, not when i drag the joystick and then toutch the right screen at the same time to make the joystick for moving only and right is for rotate but at the sametime. How can I modify my code to achieve the desired behavior?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You forgot to add the other part of the second condition, "holds the joystick with dragging or not, *and then touches the right side of the screen*".  Right now its just if you touched the right side or dragging the joystick.